# SQL Server Transaction procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, procedures

I am creating a transaction procedure. I am having a syntax error at the first if statement it says 'expecting variable' everything else is working fine not sure why it is having trouble.\here is the code

```
 Create Proc DP_Test4Transaction
    @ReorderLevel Decimal(5,0) =Null,
    @StockLevel decimal(5,0)= null,
    @StockOnOrder decimal(5,0) =null

 as
Declare @PartDescription Varchar (10)= NULL,

  //Here is where i am getting the error
If @ReorderLevel IS NULL
begin
Print 'You must enter a number for ReorderLevel' 
Print 'Order Not Processed'
print ' '
return
end


If @StockLevel is Null 
Begin
print 'A number must be entered for stocklevel'
print 'Order Not Processed'
Print ''
Return
End

If @StockOnOrder is null

Begin
Print 'A number must be entered for StockOnOrder'
Print 'Customer not inserted'
Print ''
Return
End


Begin Transaction
Insert into InventoryPart
(PartDescription,ReorderLevel,StockLevel,StockOnOrder)
Values(@PartDescription,@ReorderLevel, @StockLevel, @StockOnOrder)

Select @PartDescription = (Select Partdescription From InventoryPart
Where @PartDescription = PartDescription)

If exists (Select PartDescription from InventoryPart where Partdescription = @PartDescription)
Begin
Print ' The PartDescription'+ @PartDescription+'is already in the database'
print ' you must select a different Partdescription'
Print ' Item not inserted'
print ''
Rollback

end
else

begin
Commit Transaction
print 'Part has been added'
print ''
print ''
End
```

you probably don't need the entire code but just in case I missed something somewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have a erroneous comma after your declare statement that needs to be removed.

```
Declare @PartDescription Varchar (10)= NULL,
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx This article shows that not using a ; is depreciated.  Who knows when MS will enforce it.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the comma and try parsing the TSQL again.

```
Declare @PartDescription Varchar (10)= NULL,
```

Seems to be a syntax error.

Get in the habit of ending complete code lines (sentences) with ;

This may be required in the future.